# Adding Resource adapter ActiveMQ-rar.rar with wildfly 8.2.1

Tags: wildfly-11

I have tried added the ActiveMQ resource adapter with wildfly by using the following thread https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToUseOutOfProcessActiveMQWithWildFly

In our case we are not suppose to give the plain text in password so i have tried using the security subsystem but its throwing the following exception.

**standalone.xml**

```
<resource-adapter id="activemq-rar.rar">

                    <module slot="main" id="org.activemq"/>

                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>

                    <config-property name="ServerUrl">

                        ssl://localhost:61616

                    </config-property>

                    <connection-definitions>

                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ActivemqJms" enabled="true" pool-name="ActivemqJms">

                            <config-property name="KeyStorePassword">

                                KeyStorePassword

                            </config-property>

                            <config-property name="KeyStoreKeyPassword">

                                KeyStoreKeyPassword

                            </config-property>

                            <config-property name="TrustStore">

                                C:/ActiveMQ/conf/keystore.p12

                            </config-property>

                            <config-property name="TrustStorePassword">

                                TrustStorePassword

                            </config-property>

                            <config-property name="KeyStore">

                                C:/ActiveMQ/conf/keystore.p12

                            </config-property>

                            <xa-pool>

                                <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>

                                <max-pool-size>150</max-pool-size>

                                <prefill>false</prefill>

                                <is-same-rm-override>false</is-same-rm-override>

                            </xa-pool>

                            <security>

                                <security-domain>ActivemqRealm</security-domain>

                            </security>

                        </connection-definition>

                    </connection-definitions>

                    <admin-objects>

                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:/testqueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="testqueue">

                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">

                                testqueue

                            </config-property>

                        </admin-object>

                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic" jndi-name="java:/testtopic" use-java-context="true" pool-name="testtopic">

                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">

                                testtopic

                            </config-property>

                        </admin-object>

                </resource-adapter>


 <security-domain name="ActivemqRealm" cache-type="default">

                    <authentication>

                        <login-module name="ActivemqRealm-lm" code="com.test.EnctryptedLogin" flag="required" module="com.test.crypto">

                            <module-option name="userName" value="reportserver"/>

                            <module-option name="password" value="{AES}:SPiIQQAhcW0gDcS3e+1QjfExRCXj4ixA/EPC+bN7PMA="/>

                            <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=TxCM,name=ActivemqJms"/>

                        </login-module>

                    </authentication>

                </security-domain>
```

**Exception:**

```
16:19:58,462 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.ra.deployment."com.ca.pamsc.activemq:main_activemq-rar.rar": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.ra.deployment."com.ca.pamsc.activemq:main_activemq-rar.rar": WFLYJCA0046: Failed to start RA deployment [activemq-rar.rar]

        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService$2.run(AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:332)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

Caused by: org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.DeployException: IJ020056: Deployment failed: file:/C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/wildfly/wildfly-11.0.0.Final/modules/org/activemq/main/

        at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:2064)

        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService$WildFlyRaXmlDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.java:173)

        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterXmlDeploymentService.java:116)

        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)

        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)

        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException

        at org.jboss.msc.value.InjectedValue.getValue(InjectedValue.java:47)

        at org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.deployment.AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AbstractWildFlyRaDeployer.getSubjectFactory(AbstractResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:635)

        at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1666)

        ... 7 more





16:19:58,509 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]## Heading ##
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know what is exact solution for you case,but i share my code its work for me fine ,hope it will helpful to you also,

standalone.xml

---

```
    <mdb>
                    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:activemq-ra.rar}"/>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
  </mdb>
```

--

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:2.0">
            <server name="default">
                <security-setting name="#">
                    <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
                </security-setting>
                <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
                <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                </http-connector>
                <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-connector>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
                <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
                    <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                </http-acceptor>
                <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
                    <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
                </in-vm-acceptor>
                <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
                <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
                <jms-queue name="DeckQueue" entries="java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/DeckQueue"/>
                <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
                <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
                <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa"/>
            </server>
        </subsystem>
```

---

also i am using below value in my code,

```
     public static final String DESTINATION = "destination";
        public static final String DESTINATION_VALUE = "java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/DeckQueue";
        public static final String DESTINATION_TYPE = "destinationType";
        public static final String DESTINATION_TYPE_VALUE = "javax.jms.Queue";
public static final String QUEUE_LOOKUP = "java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/DeckQueue";
    public static final String CONNECTION_FACTORY = "java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory";//
```

Comment: Thanks @chandrakant, We are using the wildfly 8.2.1 where the activemq module is not present.